# Need help in JavaScript form validation code

Tags: javascript

can someone please explain this piece of javascript code to me line by line, in a simple manner please?
i have an external javascript file whcih goes like this;-

```
// Make this function external like I did in the video
function _(x){
return document.getElementById(x);
}

/* And all over the site from now on you can get html elements by their id 
by simply using*/
```

_("div1").innerHTML = "Hello World";

and another javascript file for form validation which goes like this

```
function restrict(elem){
var tf = _(elem);
var rx = new RegExp;
if(elem == "email"){
    rx = /[' "]/gi;
} else if(elem == "username"){
    rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
}
tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
```

Comment: Post links for resources you have searched and tried to understand. and what you cant in them to understand this

Answer (score 0):

```
function _(x){
return document.getElementById(x);
}
```

above code `_(x)` means create function with `x` parameter

and `return document.getElementById(x);` will return instance of element, so when you call `_("div1")` then call this function and return `div1` instance

Your below function it's simple check `email` and `username` validation and it will replace value match with regular expression.

If you need more help then comment me.

Comment: I have problem in understanding the last line.